# Can some one explain how to use lift in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I try to understand the lifting principle by example, and found this:

https://github.com/graninas/Functional-Design-and-Architecture/blob/1736abc16d3e4917fc466010dcc182746af2fd0e/First-Edition/BookSamples/CH03/MonadStack.hs

Then, if I change it's `lift (lift (putStrLn "bla-bla"))` to `putStrLn "bla-bla"`, the compiler throw error!

I do this base on my understanding:  `do` block are just syntax sugar, and each line's result are pass into next line. If the next line do not use the args that passed from previous line, the type of args won't cause type confliction, I think.

Take bellow as example, while  `x<- getLine`  can past compiling

```hs
test:: IO ()
test = do
  x <- getLine              -- discarded and compiler don't care it type 
  let a = "bla-bla"   -- discarded and compiler don't care it type 
  putStrLn $ "You type are discarded: "
```

Now back to the `calculations` function:

```hs
type Data = Map.Map Int String
type StateIO = StateT Data IO
type MaybeStateIO a = MaybeT StateIO a

calculations :: MaybeStateIO ()
calculations = do
    lift (lift (putStrLn "bla-bla")) -- if I change this to `putStrLn "bla-bla"`, it failed compiling.
    lift (modify (Map.insert 3 "3"))
    lift (modify (Map.insert 1 "1"))
    mb <- lift (get >>= (return . Map.lookup 1))
    lift (lift (print mb))

main = runStateT (runMaybeT calculations) Map.empty
```

I don't understand is that to compiler require lifting on `putStrLn "bla-bla"`.

Isn't it enough when return value of the last line of `do` block match the function's return value?

In this example, how does the compiler decide the `do block`'s value type？ according to function's signature?

Can anyone explains the lift for me? How do it work, when to use, etc.

Comment: `MaybeStateIO` is a `MaybeT (StateT Data IO) a` whereas `putStrLn "bla-bla" has `IO a`, it thus requires one lift to lift it to `StateT Data IO a` and another to finally lift it to a `MaybeT (StateT Data IO) a`

Answer (score 3):

The value of `calculations` is a `MaybeStateIO` value. That's the monad you are operating in, so that's what *every* line of the `do` block has to produce. But `putStrLn "bla-bla"` does *not* produce a `MaybeStateIO` value; it just produces an `IO` value. The first `lift` takes that `IO` value and returns a `StateIO` value; the second `lift` takes that `StateIO` value and returns a `MaybeStateIO` value.

Remember,

```
do
   a
   b
```

is just syntactic sugar for `a >> b`, and `(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b` needs values from the same monad as arguments. It's only the "return value" (`a` and `b`) of the monad that can vary from line to line; the monad `m` itself is fixed.

Comment: Thanks!  " (>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b needs values from the same monad as arguments. "  is what I missed. But, this requirement really bring difficult to use different monad in one do block.

Comment: And in case need to use many different monads,  does it mean that we have to define a composed monad type as `do` block's return value?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole reason monad transformers exist.

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't it enough when return value of the last line of `do` block match the function's return value?

No, since that would mean that you could write a `do` block where the first item for example would use the instance of `[]` for `Monad` whereas the next would use for example `Maybe` or `IO`, but then how would `x <- some_list` make sense for a list of `putStrLn x`? All lines in the `do` block should be of type `m a` with `m` the same instance of `Monad`, and the `a`s can have different types for each line. If you write a do block with:

```
foo = do
    x <- exp1
    exp2
```

then this is translated to `exp1 >>= \x -> exp2`, and since [`(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) operates where the two operands share the same monad `m`, this thus means that `exp1 :: m a` and `exp2 :: m b` thus need to work with the same monadic type `m`.

You require to perform lifting twice since the line should have as type `MaybeT (StateT Data IO) a` whereas `putStrLn "bla-bla"` has `IO a`, it thus requires one [**`lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) to lift it to `StateT Data IO a` and another to finally lift it to a `MaybeT (StateT Data IO) a`.

Comment: `since (>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b operates where the two operands share the same monad m`  This is the first time to aware of it, even though I knew the `do` block syntax sugar and its desugar format. So this is the key point that I have missing before.
By the way, here we can describe the situation as `monad stack`, then is the `MaybeT` the top of stack, `IO` the bottom of stack, and the `lift` function can only use to bring monad from bottom, right? 
And there are no need, no real case of bring manad from top to bottom?